# Eclipse error message in selenium in TestNg related to maven (org.testng.eclipse.maven.Maven ...)

Tags: java, eclipse, selenium, maven, testng

I am trying for the first time using an eclipse of selenium to run a TestNG program
Its code is:
When I select Run using TestNG
I get the following error message - I added below the code
Can Someone please help me with this issue?
Thanks in Advanecd

```
    import org.openqa.selenium.By;
import org.openqa.selenium.WebDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeDriver;
import org.testng.annotations.Test;
import org.testng.annotations.BeforeTest;
import org.testng.annotations.AfterTest;

public class google {
    @Test
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver", "C:\\Program Files\\Selenium\\chromedriver.exe");
        
        WebDriver driver = new ChromeDriver();
        driver.get("http://google.com");
        driver.findElement(By.xpath("//body/div[1]/div[3]/form[1]/div[2]/div[1]/div[1]/div[1]/div[2]/input[1]")).sendKeys("1234");
        driver.findElement(By.cssSelector("div.L3eUgb:nth-child(2) div.o3j99.ikrT4e.om7nvf:nth-child(3) div:nth-child(2) div.A8SBwf:nth-child(1) div.FPdoLc.tfB0Bf:nth-child(4) center:nth-child(1) > input.gNO89b")).click();
    }
```

[Error message](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KH6Qh.png)

Answer (score 0):

as Implied in this issue: [Dupe issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58543396)

```
An internal error occurred during: "Launching NewTest"
org.testng.eclipse.maven.MavenTestNGLaunchConfigurationProvider.getClasspath(Lorg/eclipse/debug/core/ILaunchConfiguration;)Ljava/util/List;
```

...implies that there was **incompatibility** between *TestNG* and *Maven* related classfiles.

Historically, this error would occur if while installing testng you have kept the checkbox for **`M2E Maven`** as checked.

The easiest approach to address this issue would be to reinstall the TestNG ensuring that the checkbox for **`M2E Maven`** is kept unchecked.